# Encryption in JSP/JSTL

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, nhibernate

I want to encrypt my value of  href tag using encryptionutils i.e.

```
<b><a href="${urlBase}?currentPath=${document.path}"><div class="directory"></div></a></b>
```

Here in GET method i need to encrypt `currentPath` that is `${document.path}` with spring encryptionutils.

There is another ways but I need to done it with encryptionutils.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that this is a Q&A site, where you post problematic code and errors and other users kindly point the issues in your code.
Please edit your post and publish what exactly have you tried so far.

Comment: This class was deprecated and removed from the codebase in 2010. Why do you need to use it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Encrypt `currentPath` in the controller and then add it as a model attribute.

```
model.addAttribute("currentPath", encodedPath);
```

Now you can use the `currentPath` attribute in your `JSP` without changes.

```
<a href="${urlBase}?currentPath=${currentPath}"></a>
```

When your next call goes to the controller with `currentPath` as a request parameter then decode `currentPath` in your controller before use.

Comment: Keep in mind that you'll need to encrypt every URL in your controller which you would like to expose in your view. This could be a repetitive task if you have URLs that are on every page. You should
introduce a proper class hierarchy for controller. If your URLs are part of your domain model and encryption is part of business requirements I wouldn't put it in the MVC layer at all. Otherwise You should consider a view helper, hence a tag function that can be used almost every in JSP (tag files, includes, etc) without poluting controller.

Answer (score 1):

Write a custom [EL function](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html#bnaiq) to encrypt your url.
Here are the basic steps:

1. Create mytagfunctions.tld under WEB-INF:

   ```
   <taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_0.xsd"
   version="2.0">

   <tlib-version>2.0</tlib-version>
   <uri>/WEB-INF/mytagfunctions.tld</uri>
   <function>
       <name>encrypt</name>
       <function-class>example.Encrypt</function-class>
       <function-signature>java.lang.String encrypt(java.lang.String)</function-signature>
   </function>
   </taglib>
   ```

Create Encrypt class in example package:

```
package example;

public class Encrypt {

    public static String encrypt(java.lang.String value) {
        String encrypted;
        //do your encryption here
        return encrypted;
    }

}
```

Include your tagfunctions in your JSP and start using it:

```
<%@ page language="java" pageEncoding="utf-8" contentType="text/html;charset=utf-8"%>

<%@ taglib prefix="string" uri="/WEB-INF/myfunctions.tld"%>

<b><a href="${urlBase}?currentPath=${string:encrypt(document.path)}"><div class="directory"></div></a></b>
```

Comment: Why go to these lengths just to encode a model attribute?

Comment: Does the OP said that he is using Spring MVC too? No. Your suggestion is tied to Spring MVC and my to JSP, respectively. The point is that I'm considerung the URL encryption as a view helper, hence a tag function that can be used almost every in JSP (tag files, includes, etc) without poluting controller. What do you do when you don't have a controller like in Spring's view-controller or views configured with Spring Security? If this encryption is part of business requirements I wouldn't put it in the MVC layer at all.

Comment: You are right @user3151168 but i need to use this path in single request mapping so this is not a good way to use it.